# Constructing a Rails form that captures an object belonging to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have the following models

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :my_object_times
end
```

and

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
end
```

In my PostGres database, the `MyObjectTime` object has a `time_in_ms` field.  So how do I construct a form that has attributes from both my `MyObject` object and my `MyObjectTime` object?  Specifically, I want to capture the `time_in_ms` field.

I have tried this:

```
<%= form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  <% if @my_object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@my_object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this hack from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @my_object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :day, class: 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Time" %>
    <%= select_tag('my_object[hour]', options_for_select((0..12).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Hour'} ) %> hrs
    <%= select_tag('my_object[minute]', options_for_select((0..60).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Minutes'} ) %> min
    <%= select_tag('my_object[second]', options_for_select((0..60).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Minutes'} ) %> sec
    <%#= f.number_field :time_in_ms %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I when submitting my form, I get and error in my controller when trying to build my model from the params:

```
def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
....
end
...
  private

    def my_object_params
      # Main Code goes here
      params[:my_object][:time_in_ms] = (params[:my_object][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:my_object][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:my_object][:second].to_i) * 1000
      params.require(:my_object).permit(:time_in_ms, :name)
    end
```

Comment: All you have to do is create the extra fields and in the controller you use that fields to create the new object

Comment: Have you tried using `fields_for`?

Comment: What is the actual goal here? Do you want to create a timer (countdown) or do you want the user to be able to select a given time?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using these objects together in more than one case I would add a virtual attribute (`attr_accessor :time_in_ms`) to your MyObject model so that it can be processed along with the standard fields. This will also get rid of the "unknown attribute" error. Then in your MyObject model you can add logic that will assign the param from your controller to it and process it as needed.  If this is the only instance where you want to be able to use both and don't have this kind of situation anywhere else in your rails app you should do what Boltzor recommended and just process this in the respective controller/action.

Comment: When you say "you can add logic that will assign the param from your controller to it," isn't that what this line, "params[:my_object][:time_in_ms] = (params[:my_object][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:my_object][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:my_object][:second].to_i) * 1000" does?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) since your both models are associated:

```
<%= f.fields_for :my_object_time do |mot| %>
  <%= mot.number_field :time_in_ms %> 
<% end %>
```

Then in your `MyObject` model add [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :my_object_times
  attr_accessible :hour, :minute, :second


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_object_times
end
```

Modify your `MyObjects` controller, white-list `my_object_time` in `my_object_params`:

```
def my_object_params
  params[:my_object][:my_object_times_attributes][:time_in_ms] = (params[:my_object][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:my_object][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:my_object][:second].to_i) * 1000
  params.require(:my_object).permit(:name, my_object_times_attributes: [:time_in_ms])
end
```

Now you will be able to save associated `MyObjectTime` while you are saving `MyObject` because of the association.

Comment: Is the f.fields_for block replacing all three select_tag declarations I have?

Comment: Do you want to replace those select tags? Right now it's not.

Comment: I'm getting the error "No association found for name `my_object_time'. Has it been defined yet?" on the line "accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_object_time".  I have copied the model exactly as you have it above.

Comment: Updated. Now you won't have to use the `fields_for` in view since we are populating in controller. Can you try both?

Comment: K, Im' getting a new error (btw, Rails complained about "attr_accessible" and recommended I use "attr_accessor", whcih I did).  When I submit my form I get "unknown attribute 'time_in_ms' for MyObject."  I replaced my "f.number_field" block with the block you provided beginning with "<%= f.fields_for :my_object_time do |mot| %>", I assume taht is what you wanted me to try.  Should I be using fields_for?

Comment: I didn't follow your instructions exactly.  When I do, I am getting the form to submit, however, right now data is only saved in my my_objects table and not in the my_object_times table.  I will have to research this a little more.

Comment: @Dave did you get the problem?